# ReadableStreamBYOBReader.read ignoring offset on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, buffer, v8

I'm trying to read a file with minimal amount of data copy using a `ReadableStreamBYOBReader`, but it seems that reader isn't reading at and writing to the correct offsets in Chrome.

In the following example, I'm simply calling `ReadableStreamBYOBReader.read` twice to see what is happening to the buffers.

The example is derived from the one on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamBYOBReader/read) (copying their example as is also produces the same behavior in the debugger)

```html
<input type="file" onchange="upload(event)" />
<script>
    async function upload(event) {
        const reader = event.target.files[0].stream().getReader({ mode: 'byob' });

        let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16777216);
        let offset = 0;

        const read1 = await reader.read(new Uint8Array(buffer, offset, 8388608));

        console.log('1', read1.value, new Uint8Array(read1.value.buffer));

        buffer = read1.value.buffer;
        offset += read1.value.byteLength;

        const read2 = await reader.read(new Uint8Array(buffer, offset, 8388608));

        console.log('2', read2.value, new Uint8Array(read2.value.buffer));
    }
</script>
```

I'm expecting `readX.value` to be the `ArrayBufferView` corresponding to what has just been read by `reader.read`. (the `ArrayBufferView` being an offset view of the 16MB buffer allocated at the beginning)

I'm expecting `new Uint8Array(readX.value.buffer)` to be the full buffer in both cases, filled with only one `reader.read`'s worth of data in the first `console.log`, and two `reader.read`'s worth of data in the second.

That's exactly what I am observing in Firefox :

```
1  Uint8Array(65536)  [   0,  0,  0, 32, 102, … ]  Uint8Array(16777216) [   0,  0,  0, 32, 102, … ]
2  Uint8Array(65536)  [ 100, 63, 56, 65, 149, … ]  Uint8Array(16777216) [   0,  0,  0, 32, 102, … ]
```

But not in Chrome :

```
1  Uint8Array(65536)  [  0,   0,  0,  32, 102, …]  Uint8Array(16777216) [   0,  0,  0, 32, 102, …]
2  Uint8Array(524288) [ 28, 196, 91, 173, 156, …]  Uint8Array(16777216) [ 100, 63, 56, 65, 149, …]
```

In the file I used for the test:

- `[  0,   0,  0,  32, 102]` is the beginning of the file
- `[100,  63, 56,  65, 149]` is offset 65536
- `[ 28, 192, 91, 173, 156]` is offset 131072

As expected, with Firefox, the two `readX.value` are the chunks that were just read, one next to the other ; and the `new Uint8Array` one is the full buffer, showing both chunks next to each other.

But with Chrome, in the second call, the `read2.value` somehow contains the content of offset 131072 (while it only read a chunk of 64k before) ; and it seems it wrote the expected content (starting from offset 65536) at the beginning of the buffer, ignoring the offset given as parameter in the second `read` call.

Note for re-testing: Chrome is annoying as it never reads chunks the same size, and sometimes read a few MB at once, thus the big 8MB buffer for reading (this behavior is not reproduced when reading to a small (few kB) ArrayBufferView)

Comment: In hindsight, it seems documentation and explanation of BYOBReader is really scarce. Is it that rarely used? And if so, why, as it avoids useless buffer copy in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report a Chrome bug, use [crbug.com/new](https://crbug.com/new) (and/or search for existing issues on [crbug.com](https://crbug.com)).

This particular issue sounds like [crbug.com/1492093](https://crbug.com/1492093), which has been fixed two weeks ago.

Comment: I wanted confirmation I wasn't misusing BYOBReader before assuming it was a Chrome bug, but crbug.com/1492093 is exactly the same issue, thanks. Google team said in a duplicate (crbug.com/1494528) this is a regression since v.118 (October 4), the fix won't be merged in v.119 (release too close). I tested v.120 and its properly fixed. We can expect it fixed in stable release December 5, 2023, according to the official schedule.